# How can i put a AWS Spotfleet behind an ElasticLoadBlancer (ELB)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there any way to put all instances of a [spotfleet](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-spotfleet-spotfleetrequestconfigdata.html) behind one ELB ? Preferably via Cloudformation.

Skimming through the documentation i could not find any hints rearding that topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now possible and it works with classic and application load balancers.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/spot-fleet-can-now-auto-attach-instances-to-your-load-balancers-and-scale-down-to-0-target-capacity/

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from amazon under an [spotfleet blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/aws/spot-fleet-update-console-support-fleet-scaling-cloudformation/) stating that this feature does not exist right now but is planned.

Answer (score -1):

Using [LaunchConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-launchconfig.html) (with a SpotPrice) connected to your AutoScalingGroup, you can have the spot fleet in your ELB.

This is a fairly standard AutoScalingGroup/LaunchConfiguration usage, the SpotPrice is the only thing that is different from the standard fleet configuration. You can combine [this basic ASG](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html#d0e23960) with [this basic LaunchConfig](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-launchconfig.html#d0e16903). I'd remove the FindInMap and Ref stuff from the latter, just replace it with the strings of your choice.

Comment: I am not sure if we are on the same page here. I specifically meant [Spotfleets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-spotfleet-spotfleetrequestconfigdata.html) as opposed to "bunch" of spot instances. Can you please clarify how your answer relates to *Spotfleets*. Sorry if i am really missing something